# Can't access screen lock type settings

Tags: lock-screens, motorola-moto-g, pattern-lock

I've recently updated my Moto G5 to Android Oreo and since then my lock screen automatically changed from pattern to swipe..
When the phone boots up it still asks me to "enter your pattern to start android device" but after the device boots up it never asks me the pattern again..

I've tried changing the lock screen but as soon as I click on change lock type I get an error "settings has stopped".
I've cleared setting app's cache, data and force stopped it, but no use.
I've cleared my security credentials
I've booted into safe mode to see if any app is causing the problem, nothing happened.

I don't want to hard reset my phone as it has a huge amount of data and taking a backup will be a huge headache

Comment: What's the current setting for lock screen? PIN/Password/Swipeup.